# Replicating arguments.callee in strict mode

Tags: javascript, function, scope, strict

I'm working in strict mode for the first time and, what-d'ya-know, it's also the first time in ages being able to use a non strict mode property would be useful. My [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10008285/preventing-infinite-recursion-when-using-backbone-style-prototypal-inheritance/10009013#10009013) outlines the exact problem I'm having, but the solution I've worked out could be adapted to something a lot more scaleable if I still had access to arguments.callee.

Without naming the function is there any way in strict mode that I can get a reference to the function whose scope I'm currently within?

Comment: You can assign your function to some variable.

Comment: Progress is a beautiful thing.

Comment: @wheresrhys - FYI, the approach for avoiding the name stopped working a few years ago, I've updated my answer in case you were relying on it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Without naming the function is there any way in strict mode that I can get a reference to the function whose scope I'm currently within?

In 2012 when [this answer was originally written](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10009764/2), there were implementation bugs with the named function expressions you were using in your linked solution. There aren't now, it's been **years** since browsers with those bugs were still in significant circulation. So here in a (very) post-IE8 world, your named function expression approach is just fine:

```
UsageGraph = Graph.extend({
   generateScale: function GS() {
       var parentMethod = this.constructor._super.generateScale;
       if(parentMethod === GS) {
           parentMethod = this.constructor._super.constructor._super.generateScale;
       }
       parentMethod.call(this); // run the parent's method
       //do additional stuff
   }
});
```

But the question asks if you can avoid having a name. In 2012, my solution if you really didn't want the function to have a name was to assign an anonymous function to a variable:

```
UsageGraph = Graph.extend(function(){
   var GS = function() {
       var parentMethod = this.constructor._super.generateScale;
       if(parentMethod === GS) {
           parentMethod = this.constructor._super.constructor._super.generateScale;
       }
       parentMethod.call(this); // run the parent's method
       //do additional stuff
   };

   return {generateScale: GS};
}());
```

But that doesn't work anymore; since ES2015, even that function has a name, inferred from the name of the variable it's assigned to:

```js
var GS = function() { };
console.log(GS.name); // "GS"
```

If you **really** don't want it to have a name, it's possible to avoid it, but you have to make an effort to defeat the automatic naming defined by the specification, for instance by making the function the return value of another function:

```js
var GS = (() => function() { })();
console.log(GS.name); // ""
```

So if avoiding the name is important, you'd do something like this:

```
UsageGraph = Graph.extend(function(){
   const generateScale = (() => function() {
       let parentMethod = this.constructor._super.generateScale;
       if(parentMethod === generateScale) {
           parentMethod = this.constructor._super.constructor._super.generateScale;
       }
       parentMethod.call(this); // run the parent's method
       //do additional stuff
   })();

   return {generateScale};
}());
```

Comment: +1 for the heads up about the <ie8 bug. But although your answer technically doesn't name the function it is still 'naming' the function in spirit. I've read up about why `callee` was deprecated, and it seems reasonable, but still a shame to lose the dynamic referencing of a function object.

Comment: @wheresrhys: (It's <IE9, not <IE8 -- big difference there.) No, it's quite true, the last example only technically avoids using a function name. My initial statement above basically says it if you put "name" in quotes, e.g.: No, you have to give the function a "name".

Comment: `generateScale: function GS() {` fails on Safari 2

Comment: @Knu - All due respect, I very much doubt that's true if used as above, that syntax is as old as JavaScript itself. But even if it were true, it woulldn't matter. :-) The last version of Safari 2 was released in 2006, **12 years ago**. It's irrelevant to today's world. :-)

Comment: I don't see who and why would want to access the callee through that thick bush of a code. Your answer is useful and correct, it's just that to me this tells that for all intents and practical purposes, it's better to just use whatever regular function reference one already has -- i.e. `function f() { f(); }`, it's at least immediately clear and can be implemented for majority, if not all, use cases.

Comment: @amn - Absolutely. As I said in the answer, *"I don't like it, but there we are. :-)"*

Comment: @LeeGoddard - Thanks for calling my attention to this old answer, although in general I strongly recommend **not** editing for style when the OP is active on the site. But there was a lot, lot more to fix in that answer with all that's changed in the intervening nine years. :-) If you were using this answer for something, you might want to read the latest version I just posted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but no... I'm not sure if this is the same manner of "naming" that you speak of:

```
var foo = function bob() {
    // call bob();
}

// bob is undeclared; here it's foo!
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4y8pY/

Comment: Be careful doing that with IE8 and earlier, it creates [two completely separate function objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) and leaks the `bob` symbol when you use a named function expression.

Comment: Also note the questioner says *"**Without** naming the function"* (my emphasis).