# Jquery - Get current event

Tags: jquery

I know I can get the event, by passing it as a parameter of the function:

```
$(".selector").on("click", function(event) {


});
```

How can I get it if it is not a parameter of the function?

For instance,

```
$(".selector").on("click", function() {

// var event = ???

});
```

Comment: Why don't you wan't it as parameter? Any Reason?

Comment: because i cannot rewrite the function.

Comment: Is that affect anything if u use event variable.. ? Try to access using this key word..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even if the parameter is not declared, it is still passed to the function, so you can write:

```
$(".selector").on("click", function() {
    var evt = arguments[0];
});
```

Comment: In a more general context, I found out that I can catch the event in this way: `function MyFunc() { var evt =  window.event || arguments.callee.caller.arguments[0] }`.

Comment: @enb081, note that `arguments.callee` is not supported in strict mode ([there are workarounds, though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10009682/replicating-arguments-callee-in-strict-mode)).

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".myform .form-control").on("input blur",function(e){

    console.dir(arguments[0].handleObj.type);

});
```

**this code can give current name of event**

may that can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below code.

```
$(".selector").on("click", function(event) {
  console.log(event.type); //output = click
});
```